# convert ANT script to Java

Tags: metadata-api, java, ant

I have been digging for almost a week into the forums and S/F Developer pages for good "basic" Java code to retrieve a package from one ORG and Deploy to another ORG.  I have had success building the ANT scripts to do this work.  ANT is limited to known objects in the Deploy ORG.  I want to delete all report folders and reload only the ones from my Package Retrieve ORG for example. I have to get more creative with the metadata-API via JAVA to clean up before replacing the reports.
I'm looking for insights others may have to begin down this path.

Super basic ANT build.xml:

```
<target name="pullmaster">
  <mkdir dir="masterdata"/>
  <sf:retrieve username="${sf.usermaster}" password="${sf.password}" sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" retrieveTarget="masterdata" packageNames="${sf.pkgName}"/>
</target>
```

Basic build.xml to push up to destination ORG:

```
<target name="pushDemo">
  <input message="Enter The DEMO ORG you want to push to:(3,4...) "   addproperty="org"  defaultvalue="0" />
  <echo message="Demo user demo${org}@myURL.com"/>
  <sf:deploy username="demo${org}@myURL.com" password="${sf.password}" sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" deployRoot="masterdata" rollbackOnError="true"/>
</target>
```

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/neowit/tooling-force.com ? It supports `deployAllDestructive` which (based on your source Org and package.xml) will remove stuff (not present in the source Org) from the destination Org before deploying what you have in the source. Not sure if `deployAllDestructive` will work for report folders, as these are tricky, but it works for normal stuff like classes/pages/objects, etc.

Comment: @gaiser Thanks for the lead.  I'll dig into this now.

Comment: You can use destructive deployment deployments from Ant. Check the documentation - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/daas_destructive_changes.htm.

Comment: If you need all meta data you can put * in the package.xml
 <types>
  <members>*</members>
  <name>ApexClass</name>
 </types>

Comment: @SLman I had not had any luck using the * wildcard on report folders in the ANT script

Comment: Do you run ant scripts as sys admin ? Make sure you have access to the reports folders.. Check Manage Public Reports option.

Comment: @SLman I did confirm that my ID is an Admin.  I do have access to the reports folders I need and I confirmed the Manage public reports is checked.  I think I need to specify: <members>Folder_name/Member_name</members> 
        <name>Dashboard</name>   To specify the folder names I would have to know them ahead of time. [http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/130598/how-to-deploy-or-retrieve-dashboard-folder]  Other thoughts - has this worked with wildcards for you?

Comment: You are correct. In the destructive deployments, you need to specify the name. Also, you need to have a empty "package.xml" file in the same folder where you have your "destructiveChanges.xml" file. Package.xml file should looks like : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata"> 
    <version>36.0</version>
</Package>