# retrieve dashboards/reports with vscode package.xml

Tags: reporting, vs-code, dashboard, retrieve

In vscode, I want to retrieve dashboards so that I can include in version control and deploy to another org. What is the syntax? I've tried using DeveloperName, replacing spaces with underscores, not replacing spaces with underscores etc.

Report: "HHN Reports/Resource Requests Last 7 Days"

```
<types>
    <members>RRM_Reports/Resource_Requests_Last_7_Days</members>
    <name>Report</name>
</types>
```

dashboard: "HHN Dashboards/Resource Requests"

```
<types>
    <members>HHN_Dashboards/Resource_Requests</members>
    <name>Dashboard</name>
</types>
```

Error:

```
Entity of type 'Dashboard' named 'HHN_Dashboards/Resource_Requests' cannot be found
```

Is there a standard Dashboard/Report syntax for package.xml? ie. replace spaces with underscores OR use the Dashboard/Report DeveloperName? I haven't found a clear explanation yet.

Comment: Are your dashboards in private folders ? Dashboards in private folders cannot be retrieved : https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/130598/how-to-deploy-or-retrieve-dashboard-folder

Comment: I don't see a way to make a folder explicitly public. I shared it with my user but I still cannot retrieve.

Comment: I was able to retrieve one of them by using DeveloperName which is an Id . . .  along with removing the space from the folder. However, the other dashboard failed to import even though it was added to package.xml the same way as the one that was retrieved.   `Metadata API received improper input. Please ensure file name and capitalization is correct. Load of metadata from db failed for metadata of type:Dashboard and file name:HHNDashboards/SzpKhetkvorZgTnNMpNJMFjLAVzBcu.`

Answer (score 3):

OK. A couple of things learned here. First, folder names in package.xml - remove spaces. Second, use DeveloperName of the Report or Dashboard to retrieve with package.xml. I got DeveloperName from workbench. Also, I had an issue retrieving one of the dashboards. Turns out it had an error that when I fixed it, I was able to retrieve.

so:
"HHN Reports/HHN Resource Requests"
becomes:

```
<types>
    <members>HHNReports/HHN_Resource_Requests_m1j</members>
    <name>Report</name>
</types>
```

and:
"HHN Dashboards/Resource Requests"
becomes:

```
<types>
    <members>HHNDashboards/SzpKhetkv4r6gTnNMpNJMFjLAVzBcu</members>
    <name>Dashboard</name>
</types>
```